# How can I add additional functionality to a class?

Tags: c++, sfml

[image]
class Button

```
Button(float x, float y, float width, float height, 
    sf::Font* font, std::string text,
    sf::Color idleColor, sf::Color hoverColor, sf::Color activeColor, bool visible = 1);
```

[image]

```
this->buttons["START_GAME"] = new Button(500, 40, 215, 55, //
        &this->font, "Начать игру",
        sf::Color(255, 50, 50, 200), sf::Color(255, 0, 0, 200), sf::Color(0, 0, 255, 200));
```

Used a translator

I have a Button class, below is the first photo, and in it I list its components. So, in SFML there is a setOutlineColor function, I want to know how to bring it into this class. I will also attach an example implementation below.

For example: we have text GAME, using sfml we can create text Game.
Then do this: Game.SetOutlineColor(sf::green)

How can i bring it to my class?

I've tried many things and still can't solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't link images with code, copy it here (as text).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Never provide pictures of code or text. Instead copy/paste your code into your question and include `\`\`\`lang` (where lang is `c`, `c++`, `bash`, `awk`, etc..) on the line above the code and `\`\`\`` (those are back-ticks) on the line below it to format as code with syntax highlight. For plain text use `\`\`\`none` on the line above, same `\`\`\`` on the line below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your object you want to change then all you need is to use the corresponding function of text and put it into eg. a function in your button class

```cpp
class Button
{
sf::Text text;
...
void setColor(sf::Color color)
{
text.setOutlineColor(color);
}
```

same goes with any other function predefined in the sfml library for drawable objects